# Map through object inside Map

Tags: reactjs

I'm having problems figuring out how to run a Map inside a Map (and go 1 level deeper)

I made a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/y011087p11), which hopefully explains what I am looking for, but I basically want to first loop through the object to get a name(header) and then loop through 1 level or so deeper to get item names.

```
{Object.keys(this.props.data.Menus).map((item, i) => (
  <div>
    <div>
      <b>{this.props.data.Menus[item].Name}</b>
    </div>
    <div>
      {Object.keys(this.props.data.Menus).map((item, i) => (
        <div>{this.props.data.Menus[item].Name}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
))}
```

Comment: how is Menus looking like?

Comment: I made a https://codesandbox.io/s/y011087p11 you can se the Menu object in TempData_NavBar.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the object the following way

```
 <div>
        {Object.keys(this.props.data.Menus).map((item, i) => (
          <div>
            <div>
              <b>{this.props.data.Menus[item].Name}</b>
            </div>
            <div>
            {this.props.data.Menus[item].MenuItems ?
              Object.keys(this.props.data.Menus[item].MenuItems).map((item1, i) => (
                  <div>{this.props.data.Menus[item].MenuItems[item1].Name}</div>))
                  :'sample'}           
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, now i see where i kept failing, because submenu3 and 4 returned null on second loop